# Write a regex that would increment a 2-digit hexadecimal number

Tags: code-challenge, regular-expression, hexadecimal

Your regex will receive a string of the form

```
!XX!

#<extra>
```

where `X` is any hexadecimal digit (0-9 and A-F **capital letters only**), and `<extra>` is a character sequence to your choosing. (perhaps something like `0123456789ABCDEF0` could be useful?)

You may use any regex flavour.

Scoring will be calculated as: find regex length + replace length + custom string length. lowest score wins.

Your submission must include which flavour you are using, the find regex, the replace string, and your extra string, all of their lengths, and the total length.

**test cases:**

```
!00!

#<extra>
```

Expected output:

```
!01!

#<extra>
```

---

```
!AC!

#<extra>
```

Expected output:

```
!AD!

#<extra>
```

---

```
!2F!

#<extra>
```

Expected output:

```
!30!

#<extra>
```

---

```
!FF!

#<extra>
```

Expected output:

```
!00!

#<extra>
```

---

Comment: Welcome to the site. All questions must have a scoreable winning criterion.  What is the winning criterion for this? Is it code/regex golf (shortest code)?

Comment: @LevelRiverSt "Scoring will be calculated as: find regex length + replace length + custom string length. lowest score wins."

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>58</s> score: 21 + 2 + 17 = 40 bytes

Using PCRE substitution

```perl
s/(\w)(?=F?.
#.*?\1(.))/$2/g
```

with extra

```perl
0123456789ABCDEF0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YXyOmXFPD3tbNXo9LWU/LPsZQQ09TU1/FSD/9/39FAwNFLmUDQyNjE1MzcwtLRydnF1c3Ay5FR2fs4kZu2MXdsIv/yy8oyczPK/6va2Bubl4AAA)

First solution overcomplicated

```perl
s/(\w)(F)?(?=.
#.*?\1(.).*(?(2)F(.)))/$3$4/g
```

with extra

```perl
0123456789ABCDEF0F0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 20 + 2 + 17 = 39 bytes

```
(\w)(?=F*!¶¶.*\1(.))
$2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qkaDCdWjboW3KBoZGxiamZuYWlo5Ozi6ubgb/NWLKNTXsbd20FEEK9LRiDDX0NDW5VIz@G7on/Fc0MFDkUjQwBBKOziDCBUgYuQEJY5CEG4gFVAIA) Linked test suite automatically adds and removes the extra string.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 3+25+0 = 28

```perl
s/\w+/sprintf"%02X",1+hex$&&255/e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YP6ZcW7@4oCgzryRNSdXAKEJJx1A7I7VCRU3NyNRUP/X/f0UDA0UuZS5FR2cwZeQGptxA1L/8gpLM/Lzi/7oG5ubmBQA)

3 chars in `\w+`.

25 in `sprintf"%02X",1+hex$&&255` where `$&` is the found input hex number.

0 extra chars after `#`.